# Bootstrap 4 div padding issue

Tags: css

I am using this structure but

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      Your card
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      Your card
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      Your card
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      Your card
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      Your card
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      Your card
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      Your card
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For some reason the   has as much padding as it would take to "match" the next div in the horizontal row. For example, if the first div is text, then the second is text, and the third is an image...the first two divs "grow" to be the size of the third. I thought with this Bootstrap 4 it was supposed to be flexible? Thanks.

Comment: Couple thoughts?   Bootstrap is based on 12 column grid, i think you're specifying 28 (4x7).  Do you intent to have 7 columns here (hard to tell without seeing the css).  If so, you would have like col-sm-1, col-sm-2, col-sm-2, col-sm-2, col-sm-2, col-sm-2, col-sm-1  7 not really pretty in bootstrap eh?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 utilizes flexbox (display: flex) for a lot of it's layout, including it's cards. That is the reason that all the cards grow in accordance to it's siblings. You can learn more about flexboxes here:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

and

https://demos.scotch.io/visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-flexbox-playground/demos/

Answer (score 0):

You're using col-sm-4 which will make all the columns be the same size which may be what you're referring to as the first two divs grow. If you mean something else, I would look into how Bootstrap 4 works with flexbox which may also help you understand how the columns act in Bootstrap 4

Comment: It seems like it's the... "col-4" part that has the Space. the card doesn't when I "inspect" in Chrome...just the div class with the col-4....
     <div class="row">

  
  <div  class="col-4" style="display:flex;flex-shrink:2;flex-direction:column;">
   
    <div class="card">

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the images can push out the divs. Set a style to the image to be `width: 100%` and see if that makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

Ok this works. Thanks everyone above for your help, I took many things from it to get the answer. It turns out if I'm reading this correctly flex itself won't allow for "three columns with shrunken divs" so one div can be bigger than the others but they all shrink to their own respective sizes around their content. So I used Masonry. I just included the .js in my head section as a script reference then  added the below. If you aren't using .NET (meaning you're using PHP) just erase out the itemtemplate and repeater stuff...the code is the same for you.

```
 <div class="row" style="display:flex;" data-masonry='{ "gutter": 0, "itemSelector": ".col-4" }'>

 <asp:repeater id="ItemsList" runat="server">
```

```
             <div class="card">
```